# Why Java variable cannot be resolved inside an IF Statement?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%
    if (group.isControlPanel()) {
        String cssClassContainer = "container";
    } else {
        String cssClassContainer = "container-fluid";
    }
%>
```

I get a compile error when I define a variable inside If Statement: `An error occurred at line: 40 in the jsp file: /page.jsp__cssClassContainer cannot be resolved to a variable.`

When I remove If Statement I don't get any error:

```
<%
        String cssClassContainer = "container";
%>
```

Why?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a common problem for people who move from Javascript to Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You restricted the scope of the the variable  `cssClassContainer`

You might want

```
<%
    String cssClassContainer=""; // or null
    if (group.isControlPanel()) {
         cssClassContainer = "container";
    } else {
         cssClassContainer = "container-fluid";
    }
%>
```

What happened with your code now is the scope of variable `cssClassContainer`  restricted to `{}`

Out side of that you cannot access.

The above condition can replace by (Skeets magic :)) ,

```
 String cssClassContainer = group.isControlPanel()? "container" : "container-fluid";
```

Comment: IMO it would be clearer not to assign a value *at all* in the declaration, as both paths will assign a value. Another alternative would be to use the conditional operator, of course: `String cssClassContainer = group.isControlPanel() ? "container" : "container-fluid";`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes Jon, I'm on your way :) Updated.